# Why flagged post on Aug 8 at 18:55 is still in pending status?

Tags: bug

I have a flagged a question for off-topic on Aug 8 at 18:55. It is still showing "**pending**".

But other flagged posts which were flagged after 8th August, are in helpful/declined status. Below is the screen shot

[image]

***Why this specific flagged post status is still pending?***

Comment: Close flags go to the close queue, which is always full; not-an-answer flags go to the low quality queue, which is emptied regularly.  You shouldn't expect flags to be handled in order of submission, in general.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a duplicate of the marked question. The other question relates to non-custom flags, which direct the post to a review queue. The above relates to a custom flag, which directs the post to the moderators' queue. In both cases, it's possible for a flag to remain active/pending for an extended period of time, but the reasons for that are different. Non-custom flags stay active when no other user has voted the same, preventing the post from being put in a review queue. Custom flags stay pending when the moderators' queue has a large backlog.

Comment: Ironically, there's a later question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309059/what-about-these-two-flags-and-what-is-the-maximum-limit-of-a-flag-could-remain that IMHO _is_ a duplicate of this one.