# What about these two flags and what is the maximum limit of a flag could remain pending?

Tags: discussion, flags

I have flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31279158/unicode-characters-like-emoticons-in-telegram-bot-message-or-keyboard/32991661#32991661) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555966/why-userprincipal-enabled-returns-different-values/33004264#33004264) answers 22 and 21 days before respectively where the authors told that they have written answer because they do not have enough reputation to comment. But still the flags are in `pending` state. I flagged them in custom moderation, so that moderators could convert them to comment (as far I knew, moderators could do it).

As far I know, a flag could remain in pending state up to 15 days. I might have seen it in Meta Stack Exchange, but I don't know about the period in Stack Overfolw.

So, I want to know:

- Why such obvious flags remains in pending state such a long time? and what should I do in such cases?
- What is the maximum duration of a flag could remain in pending state (or time before aged away)?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why such obvious flags remains in pending state such a long time?

Because you chose to flag them for moderator attention with a custom flag rather than using "not an answer". Custom flags aren't categorized or sorted by "obviousness", since they're all custom and there's no way the system can analyze them based on their contents or their context.

We have upwards of 700 custom flags pending in our queue right now, which is way more than we should have, out of a total of more than 2000. I say way more than we should have, because the majority of these custom flags, which includes yours, end up being for reasons that *don't* warrant a custom flag, but we nevertheless have to process them which takes time.

> What is the maximum duration of a flag could remain in pending state (or time before aged away)?

Custom flags remain in the queue indefinitely until they're handled.

> I flagged them in custom moderation, so that moderators could convert them to comment (as far I knew, moderators could do it).

On Stack Overflow, not already having the privilege to post comments is not a valid reason to convert an answer to a comment.

> and what should I do in such cases?

Please don't flag these for our attention; we won't convert them. Just flag them as "not an answer".